# Проскакивает работа программы в if else

Tags: c++, visual-c++, struct, if

Нужно определить направление ветра в заданной местности и по заданной дате. Проблема в том, что 5 пункт (определение ветра) не выводит нужную информацию.

```html
#include "pch.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib> 
 
using namespace std;

struct Weather //cтруктура "Погода"
{
 string local; //Район местности
 string data; //Дата
 int day; //День
 int count; //Количество осадков
 double intensity; //Интенсивность осадков
 double speed; //Скорость ветра
 int temp; //Средняя температура за день
 string direction; //Направление ветра 
 string afternoon; //температура днем
 string night;//температура ночью
} s[100];
int add(int n) //Прибавление информации в базу
{
 cout << "local: " << endl;
 cin >> s[n].local;
 cout << "data: " << endl;
 cin >> s[n].data;
 cout << "day: " << endl;
 cin >> s[n].day;
 cout << "precipitation: \n" << endl;
 cout << "count: ";
 cin >> s[n].count;
 cout << " intensiv: " << endl;
 cin >> s[n].intensity;
 cout << "wind \n";
 cout << "speed: " << endl;
 cin >> s[n].speed;
 cout << "direction: " << endl;
 cin >> s[n].direction;
 cout << " average  temperature: " << endl;
 cin >> s[n].temp;
 cout << "afternoon: " << endl;
 cin >> s[n].afternoon;
 cout << "night: " << endl;
 cin >> s[n].night;
 return ++n;
}
void Out(int n) //Вывод базы
{
 cout << "INFORM PRO BAZU: " << endl;
 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
 {
  cout << "local: " << s[i].local << endl;
  cout << "data: " << s[i].data << endl;
  cout << "\n";
  cout << "precipitation: \n" << endl;
  cout << "count: " << s[i].count << endl;
  cout << "intensity" << s[i].intensity << endl;
  cout << "wind \n" << endl;
  cout << "speed: " << s[i].speed << endl;
  cout << "direction: " << s[i].direction << endl;
  cout << "\n";
  cout << "average  temperature: " << s[i].temp << endl;
  cout << "afternoon: " << s[i].afternoon<< endl;
  cout << "night:  " << s[i].night << endl;
 }

}
void t(int n) // Температура где +10 градусов
{

 string dat = 0;

 cout << " add  dat: ";
 cin >> dat;
 bool present = false;
 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
 {
  cout << "vivod inform \n" << endl;
  if (s[i].data == dat && s[i].temp == 10)
  {
   cout << "local  " << s[i].local << endl;
   present = true;
  }
 }
 if (!present)
  cout << dat << " there was no temperature of 10 degrees " << endl;
}
void average(int n) //Среднее количество осадков
{
 string loc;
 cout << " add local \n" << endl;
 cin >> loc;

 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
 {
  if (s[i].local == loc)
  {

   if (s[i].day != 0) // Если выполняется условие
   {
    double precipitation = (double)s[i].count / s[i].day;
    cout << "average precipitation " << precipitation << endl;
   }
   
  }
  else
   cout << "average precipitation = 0 " << endl; // Если не выполняется условие
 }

}
void wind(int n) //Определение направление ветра в заданный день и в заданную дату
{
 string locaal;
 string date;
 cout << "local " << endl;
 cin >> locaal;
 cout << "date " << endl;
 cin >> date;
 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
 {
  if (s[i].local == locaal)
  {
   if (s[i].direction == s[i].data)
   {
    cout << "direction was " << s[i].direction << endl;
    cout << " date " << s[i].data << endl;
   }
  }
  else 
   cout << "error! " << endl;
 }
}
int main()
{
 cout << "menu" << endl;
 int n = 0;
 while (1)
 {
  cout << "1 - add;" << endl <<
   "2 - all baza" << endl <<
   "3 - local 10" << endl <<
   "4 - average precipitation " << endl<<
   "5 - direction wind" <<endl;
  int a; cin >> a;
  switch (a)
  {
  case 1:
   system("cls");
   n = add(n);
   system("cls");
   break;
  case 2:
   Out(n);
   break;
  case 3:
   t(n);
   break;
  case 4:
   average(n);
  break;
  case 5:
  wind(n);
  break;
  }
  
 }
 system("pause");
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Сравнения даты и направления ветра `s[i].direction == s[i].data` явно опечатка

Comment: тогда что с чем нужно сравнивать?

Comment: @Evgeny_L Ну раз у пользователя спрашиваете дату, то наверное введенную дату и нужно сравнивать, не? Вы хоть отлаживать свой код пробовали?

Comment: Пробовал. 
Изменил строку s[i].direction == s[i].data на строку (s[i].direction == date)
Ошибка не исчезла.

Comment: @Evgeny_L `(s[i].direction == date)` - это по-прежнему сравнение направления ветра с датой, только теперь с введенной пользователем

Comment: Извините, но я не совсем вас понимаю. Можете показать на конкретную ошибку?

Comment: @Evgeny_L Куда уж конкретнее...

Comment: Кодом, если можно. Тогда точно пойму.

Comment: @Evgeny_L Как же вы умудрились столько написать и застряли на таком очевидном?

Comment: Сижу уже просто слишком много часов над этим. Вот и сломался так сказать.

Comment: Так все же в чем ошибка? Покажите кодом, пожалуйста.

Comment: @Evgeny_L Вам кодом и показали. Вы , условно, температуру сравниваете с давлением, а Вам говорят что температуру нужно сравнивать с температурой, Вы же в ответ говорите что не понимаете в чём ошибка и просите сравнить температуры за вас.